# If text boxes are not empty check checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to figure out how to check if all 4 inputs are filled out then checkmark the contact information check box. If any are not filled out uncheck the checkbox.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

```js
$(document).on('change', '#ContactName, #ContactEmail, #ContactPhone', function() {

        if ('#ContactName, #ContactEmail, #ContactPhone' === '') {
$("#contactinformation").prop("checked", false);
} else {
$("#contactinformation").prop("checked", true);
                
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-lg-7">
  <div class="form-group">
   <label for="ContactName">Contact name:</label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="ContactName" id="ContactName" size="40" maxlength="120" value="" />
  </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
 <div class="col-lg-7">
  <div class="form-group">
   <label for="BusinessName">Business name:</label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="BusinessName" id="BusinessName" size="40" maxlength="120" value="" />
  </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
 <div class="col-lg-7">
  <div class="form-group">
   <label for="ContactEmail">Email address:</label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="ContactEmail" id="ContactEmail" size="40" maxlength="80" value="" />
  </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
 <div class="col-lg-7">
  <div class="form-group">
   <label for="ContactPhone">Phone number (business hours):</label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="ContactPhone" id="ContactPhone" size="40" maxlength="50" value="" />
  </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
 <div class="col-lg-12">
  <div class="form-group">
   <input type="checkbox" name="contactinformation" id="contactinformation" />
   Contact information
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Or are you completely new to JavaScript? In that case SO would not be the right place for this... If not, please show us what you tried so far (other than the pseudo code).

Comment: Protip: Don't use IDs. Use a common class so you can specify just one selector in your script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer updated to reflect new requirement that `BusinessName` be optional.

See the comments inline:

```js
// Set up a blur event handler for each text field
$('.form-control:not("#BusinessName")').on("blur", function(evt) {
  let count = 0; // Keep track of how many are filled in

  // Loop over all the text fields
  $('.form-control:not("#BusinessName")').each(function(idx, el){
    // If the field is not empty....
    if(el.value !== ""){
      count++; // Increase the count
    }
  });

  // Test to see if all 3 are filled in
  if(count === 3){
    $("#contactinformation").prop("checked", true);  // Check the box
  } else {
    $("#contactinformation").prop("checked", false); // Unheck the box
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-lg-7">
  <div class="form-group">
   <label for="ContactName">Contact name:</label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="ContactName" id="ContactName" size="40" maxlength="120" value="" />
  </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
 <div class="col-lg-7">
  <div class="form-group">
   <label for="BusinessName">Business name:</label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="BusinessName" id="BusinessName" size="40" maxlength="120" value="" />
  </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
 <div class="col-lg-7">
  <div class="form-group">
   <label for="ContactEmail">Email address:</label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="ContactEmail" id="ContactEmail" size="40" maxlength="80" value="" />
  </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
 <div class="col-lg-7">
  <div class="form-group">
   <label for="ContactPhone">Phone number (business hours):</label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="ContactPhone" id="ContactPhone" size="40" maxlength="50" value="" />
  </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
 <div class="col-lg-12">
  <div class="form-group">
   <input type="checkbox" name="contactinformation" id="contactinformation" disabled />
   Contact information
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @DavidBrierton You'd just change the selector that's used to: `$('.form-control:not("#BusinessName")')` and change the test to check for `3`.

Comment: @DavidBrierton Answer updated to show this. Just FYI, this was not part of your original question. In fact, you specifically asked how to make all 4 have to have values. In the future, if you have a change in your requirements, please either edit your question to reflect those or post a new question.

Comment: @DavidBrierton You're welcome. Don't forget to mark as "the" answer.

Comment: @DavidBrierton Adding the `disabled` attribute to the checkbox does the trick.

Answer (score 2):

Please try with below code snippet.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control input-sm InputText" name="BusinessName" id="BusinessName" size="40" maxlength="120" value="" />




 $( document ).ready(function() {
    $(".InputText").change(function(){
var checkCheckBox= true; 
         $(".InputText").each(function() {
                 if ($.trim($(this).val()) != '') {
                     checkCheckBox = false;
                }
                });

         if (checkCheckBox == true)

        {
            $("#contactinformation").prop("checked",true);
        }
        else
        {


    $("#contactinformation").prop("checked",false);
            }
        });
    });
```

Add "InputText" class in textbox,  if you want to validate this thing.

Comment: Setting the attribute after setting the property is overkill.

Comment: I agree with you but sometimes only "prop()" or "attr()" is not working in all version of IE browser so i have added both.

Comment: Huh. That's not true. If you are experiencing that, then you aren't using `.attr()` and/or `.prop` correctly. There is no IE issue with their use.